# Should I sign X headers in DKIM?

Tags: email, rfc, email-headers, dkim

I'm using Postfix + OpenDKIM to send emails. Should I sign X headers (X-Confirm-Reading-To, X-Unsubscribe, X-Priority, etc) in DKIM?

```
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=simple/simple;
    d=mydomain.com; s=mail; t=1435840997;
    i=no-reply@mydomain.com;
    bh=5n7rgNH/UhgzXvjmn6zu+M1BL29tq5L9PEZ7SB3uQgI=;
    h=To:Subject:Message-Id:From:X-Confirm-Reading-To:
     Disposition-Notification-To:Return-Receipt-To:List-Unsubscribe:
     List-Id:Date:X-Unsubscribe:X-Priority;
    b=vxfGzczj3S4wm1QtlrPPisyi2FsbDPP+gSSEyx/VWd09xdqSiLwdsn5vJS3SF5KoB
     etbHaJvmfvpbklJLwDPM4g7rRKaRmYXE3X02+E/DzsHFEz3TNPhPfkhNslMefRLf3h
     uq+juAwccQkzjxvvF5W4pukSJr1+Rw7NviukpZT5RSusiKSmJjFLjQavKCFSFme/bR
     u2zTCMEN1JUE5cLXKJV6aFfTl16HRXYimTNvI2pLGJijxku8zKaxrgQevQJM4v3EDX
     vs+gtOhw9t3kJI6OJsmJJyifiBRadl0/D3WUpvqYKGGFyzFPb28zvsI+h/AAOmapbM
     4WeE3vdYLb2Hg==
```

Which headers should be signed in DKIM?

Answer (score 2):

You can sign custom X- headers, but it's not required.

From http://dkim.org/specs/rfc4871-dkimbase.html#choosing-header-fields:

> The following header fields SHOULD be included in the signature, if they are present in the message being signed:
>
> From (REQUIRED in all signatures)
>
> Subject
>
> Date, Message-ID
>
> To, Cc
>
> MIME-Version
>
> Content-Type, Content-Transfer-Encoding, Content-ID, Content-Description
>   Resent-Date, Resent-From, Resent-Sender, Resent-To, Resent-Cc, Resent-Message-ID
>
> In-Reply-To, References
>
> List-Id, List-Help, List-Unsubscribe, List-Subscribe, List-Post, List-Owner, List-Archive
>
> The following header fields SHOULD NOT be included in the signature:
>
> Return-Path
>
> Received
>
> Comments, Keywords
>
> Bcc, Resent-Bcc
>
> DKIM-Signature
>
> Optional header fields (those not mentioned above) normally SHOULD NOT be included in the signature, because of the potential for additional header fields of the same name to be legitimately added or reordered prior to verification. There are likely to be legitimate exceptions to this rule, because of the wide variety of application-specific header fields that may be applied to a message, some of which are unlikely to be duplicated, modified, or reordered.

Comment: If you want to allow the DKIM to validate even when the message is passed through mailing lists, you should not include Subject or the full body in the signature. This is because many mailing list programs modify subject line and/or body of the message. Of course, this reduces the proof value of the signature so it's a compromise you may or may not want to do.

Answer (score 0):

There's no compelling reason not to: it wastes a few bytes, that's all. If you get more benefit than the cost then sign them.